# Create multidimensional array from flat file array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, structure, flat

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = array(
    'home.js' => new File(),
    'view/index.html' => new File(),
    'src/index.js' => new File(),
    'src/libs/jquery.js' => new File()
);
```

Now I want to convert in a structure like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => home.js
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => view
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => index.html
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => src
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => index.js
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => libs
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => jquery.js
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I tried for hours, with help of StackOverfow answers but I couldn't come up with a solution as all other questions have a different setup.

---

**Edit:**

What I got so far with the help of SO is (can't remember the exact answer though):

```
$out = array();
foreach($arr as $path => $file) {
    $parts = explode('/', trim($path, '/'));

    applyChain($out, $parts, $file);
}

function applyChain(&$arr, $parts, $value)
{
    if (!is_array($parts)) {
        return;
    }

    if (count($parts) == 0) {
        $arr = $value;
    } else {
        array_shift($parts);
        applyChain($arr[], $parts, $value);
    }
}

print_r($out);
```

I don't know how exactly it works, especially the part `applyChain($arr[] ...`). It kinda works with the depth, but not with the file names. I get following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => File Object
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => File Object
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => File Object
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => File Object
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: A recursive function and explode might help. BTW, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I edited my question with what I tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be a solution in a few lines using `explode()` and `eval()`. But `eval()` is not considered clean, so lets try recursion:

```
<?php

class File {
}

$arr = array(
    'home.js' => new File(),
    'view/index.html' => new File(),
    'src/index.js' => new File(),
    'src/libs/jquery.js' => new File()
);

function sub($path) {
        $rv = array();
        $parts = explode('/', $path, 2);           // strip off one level
        $rv['text'] = $parts[0];                   // put it into 'text' element
        if (count($parts)>1)                       // is there anything left?
                $rv['children'] = sub($parts[1]);  // do the same for the rest of the path

        return $rv;
}

$new = array();
foreach (array_keys($arr) as $file) {
        $new[] = sub($file);
}

var_dump($new);

?>
```

But, as Peter commented, this creates seperate substructures even if the pathes have some part in common (like `src/libs/jquery.js` and `src/libs/melon.js`).

With the use of ugly `eval()` (which can be replaced later) I got the following code:

```
<?php

class File {
}

$arr = array(
    'home.js' => new File(),
    'view/index.html' => new File(),
    'src/index.js' => new File(),
    'src/libs/jquery.js' => new File(),
    'src/libs/melon.js' => new File(),
);

// conversion
function sub($element) {
        $rv = array();
        foreach (array_keys($element) as $sub) {
                $part['text'] = $sub;
                if (is_array($element[$sub])) {
                        $part['children'] = sub($element[$sub]);
                }
                $rv[] = $part;
        }
        return $rv;
}

// create array with path file/folder names as keys
$new = array();
foreach (array_keys($arr) as $row) {
        $def = '$new["'.preg_replace('&/&', '"]["', $row).'"] = 1;';
        eval($def);
}

// run
$new2 = sub($new);
var_dump($new2);

?>
```

This outputs

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["text"]=>
    string(7) "home.js"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["text"]=>
    string(4) "view"
    ["children"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(10) "index.html"
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["text"]=>
    string(3) "src"
    ["children"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(8) "index.js"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(4) "libs"
        ["children"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(1) {
            ["text"]=>
            string(9) "jquery.js"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(1) {
            ["text"]=>
            string(8) "melon.js"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is great! Thanks for this so far. Do you see an easy solution for multiple files in a folder? Like: `'src/libs/jquery.js' => new File(), 'src/libs/melon.js' => new File()`. This would generate a whole new 'root' array. But I would rather have it inside the children array of 'libs'. Anyway, thank you so much for the great start.

Comment: I would have generally used the parts as keys, in my opinion the text/children structure is more complicated as it need to be. So you would get: `[home.js] => 1, [view] => [index.html] => 1, [src] => [lib] => array([jquery.js] => 1, [melon.js] => 1)` (its not really var_dump syntax, but I hope you get what I mean). This could then be output to your structure as well.

Comment: I agree with you, that it's more complicated than it needs to be. Unfortunately it's handed to another tool which needs this kind of structure :(

Comment: Ok, thank you. `eval` is not the best solution, but has to do it for now.

Comment: Of course, but i had to find a fast and easy solution, because I did not have any more time.

Comment: An eval-free solution could be done by storing references to the nodes with the sub-paths as keys... you see, it still haunts me =)

Comment: Ah I see! Yes, it got much trickier than I wanted it to be :).